# Create a responsive layout in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new Bootstrap and have been trying to get my head around documentation but finding it a bit confusing.
My page has three blocks: a main header, a side navigation, and a main content.
I could easily do a layout with CSS but I am using Bootstrap and wanted to use this to do a responsive layout.
On a regular screen I would like it to be as follows (where header takes full width):

```
[HEADER]
[NAV][MAIN]
```

Then on a small screen:

```
[HEADER]
[NAV]
[MAIN]
```

But on a smallscreen I would like nav to be collapsed. My nav is "nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav" and I am not sure how to get that effect with this.

Thanks very much for any help.

Here is the html. Not that it gives you much more info.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>title</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul id="nav" class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav" >
            <li><a class="parent">item 1</a>
                <ul class="bs-docs-sidenav" style="display:none;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    subitem 1
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="content">
        <p>content</p>
    </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use col-*-*
This tells you how many columns the block should take up on different size screens.
Still would like the menu box to shrink into 1 item on a small screen, but this is good enough.

```
<header class="row col-xs-12">
</header>
<nav class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-4 ">
</nav>
<main class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
</main>
```